# Invisible jQuery Mobile Popup issue on Android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, popup

I have some issue with jQuery mobile popup on my android device. Im using a Android device with OS 4.4.4. Building the app using phonegap/cordova.

This is how I replicate the issue. First I will reach a page, press a button to trigger a condition to activate the popup, after which I will press back or the button on the popup to close it, when I press the button again, the popup condition is met, but the popup is not showing properly, it is invisible.

What could be the possible cause of this? Hope to get some help here, I've attached my code at the bottom of this question.

Thanks in advance!

```
//When condition met, it will execute the following function with header and text parse in as string
    function openBox(header, text) {
        $("#message-header").html(header);
        $("#message-text").html(text);
        $("#message").popup("open");
    }

function closeBox() {
  $("#message").popup("close");    
}




<div data-role="popup" id="message" class="pop-up pop-up-std" data-overlay-theme="b" data-dismissible="false">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 id="message-header">Header</h2>
            <div class="msgBox">
                <div id="message-text" class="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn ui-btn" data-rel="back" onclick="closeBox()">Start</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a fixed for it...
It is to rearrange the popup, if you have multiple popups within a screen, those that are below will have such issue. So to fix it, bring the generic popup to the top of all the other popups.